# onchange of dropdownlist not clearing second dropdownlist(cascade one)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two `dropdownlist` in my page.

what I want is, if the value of first `dropdownlist` is changed the second value of `dropdownlist` should set to default value which is **"--Select--"** but it is not happening.

Here is my code:-

```
("#ddlAdjustmentType").change(function (evt) {
            $("#ddlItemdesc option:eq(0)").prop("selected", true);});
```

but the same is working on for the other dropdownlist which is cascaded to that list

```
 $("#ddlItemCode").change(function (evt) {
            $("#ddlItemdesc option:eq(0)").prop("selected", true);});
```

Please suggest how to make default onchange of `ddlAdjustmentType` dropdownlist

Comment: How the other drop down list is filled? upon selecting an item from the AdjustmentType DDL? If yes would you add that code?

Comment: Other drop down list are filled on the basis of Ajax..its been interconnected. Also I m travelling so can't post the code.. Other than that let me know what u want

Comment: I wan't you to be happy and since you are travelling.. ENJOY IT :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the dropdownlist was the cascading one, I need to make changes from where it was binding. SO I did like below on the function

```
var strval = "";
        var strdesc = document.getElementById('ddlItemdesc').value;
        //alert(desc1.length)
        for (var i = 0; i < desc1.length; i++) {
            StrPriBuild = desc1[i].split('~');
            ObjPriCtrl = document.createElement("OPTION");
            ObjPriCtrl.text = StrPriBuild[0];
            ObjPriCtrl.value = StrPriBuild[0];
            strval = StrPriBuild[0];
            document.getElementById(id).options.add(ObjPriCtrl)
        }

        if (strval != "") {
            document.getElementById('ddlItemdesc').value = strval;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('ddlItemdesc').value = "0";
        }
    }
```

and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
// sets selected index to first item using the DOM
$("select#elem")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

// sets selected index to first item using jQuery (can work on multiple elements)

```
`$("select#elem").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Comment: your both the solution is not working, as it is not getting set to default. Also my dropdownlist is `asp.net` control. not the html control

Answer (score 0):

You can use empty like below

```
$("#ddlAdjustmentType").change(function (evt) {
    $("#ddlItemdesc").val("");
})
```